# SVG clip-path objectBoundingBox cut the image

Tags: svg, background-image, clip-path

i will use clip-path with svg. but the "image"/div will cut on the on the edge.
i don't know what iam doing wrong.

```css
.clipped{
    width:400px;
  height:400px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
}

.clipped2 {
  clip-path: url(#clip-shape2);
  background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/300/450);
}
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip-shape2" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox" transform="scale(0.0070)">
<path d="M33.973,139.881c1.409-0.981,2.847-1.913,4.322-2.773c0.104-0.063,0.199-0.136,0.306-0.195
    c0.043-0.029,0.089-0.047,0.134-0.072c0.84-0.482,1.7-0.928,2.56-1.369c0.444-0.229,0.88-0.478,1.325-0.692
    c0.469-0.229,0.949-0.428,1.423-0.64c8.617-3.954,17.746-5.886,26.769-5.886c0.004,0,0.034,0,0.052,0
    c8.008-0.008,15.911-1.718,23.202-4.936c0.664-0.299,1.334-0.578,1.988-0.901c0.181-0.086,0.355-0.188,0.533-0.276
    c0.982-0.495,1.964-1.008,2.932-1.567c0.066-0.037,0.132-0.081,0.201-0.121c1.039-0.604,2.057-1.235,3.045-1.893
    c0.178-0.118,0.348-0.25,0.522-0.371c0.856-0.584,1.694-1.183,2.511-1.805c0.312-0.239,0.614-0.495,0.923-0.741
    c0.651-0.523,1.301-1.045,1.927-1.592c0.442-0.392,0.874-0.802,1.312-1.206c0.459-0.43,0.925-0.851,1.37-1.294
    c0.577-0.574,1.135-1.178,1.691-1.78c0.274-0.3,0.562-0.589,0.828-0.891c0.729-0.824,1.432-1.679,2.113-2.552
    c0.081-0.101,0.17-0.201,0.249-0.305c1.57-2.027,3.021-4.184,4.343-6.471c0.009-0.017,0.027-0.028,0.039-0.046
    c5.006-8.726,7.659-18.645,7.659-28.707c-0.006-9.732-2.477-19.584-7.698-28.623c-0.642-1.113-1.318-2.194-2.022-3.249
    c-0.028-0.042-0.054-0.086-0.079-0.128c-0.622-0.923-1.276-1.812-1.943-2.688c-0.128-0.168-0.24-0.343-0.372-0.508
    c-0.462-0.594-0.947-1.154-1.433-1.727c-2.533-3.001-5.356-5.742-8.446-8.168c-0.209-0.164-0.405-0.338-0.615-0.496
    c-0.59-0.447-1.199-0.865-1.804-1.293c-0.434-0.302-0.855-0.617-1.292-0.908c-0.42-0.274-0.852-0.528-1.275-0.795
    c-0.661-0.411-1.312-0.826-1.985-1.209c-0.229-0.132-0.467-0.249-0.703-0.379c-0.887-0.486-1.775-0.966-2.684-1.404
    c-0.037-0.02-0.074-0.034-0.115-0.052c-6.634-3.189-13.832-5.089-21.182-5.573c-1.235-0.078-2.478-0.124-3.731-0.124
    c-1.812,0-3.598-0.101-5.373-0.246c-0.33-0.027-0.661-0.067-0.991-0.102c-1.575-0.154-3.131-0.364-4.672-0.631
    c-0.207-0.036-0.414-0.069-0.622-0.105c-3.71-0.679-7.309-1.669-10.77-2.952c-0.01-0.004-0.019-0.007-0.026-0.013
    c-1.71-0.633-3.38-1.341-5.017-2.111c-0.134-0.064-0.271-0.125-0.406-0.189c-3.249-1.559-6.343-3.377-9.263-5.436
    c-0.38-0.27-0.753-0.546-1.128-0.822c-1.087-0.804-2.148-1.639-3.183-2.508c-0.243-0.205-0.508-0.382-0.751-0.592
    c0.018,0.091,0.021,0.181,0.039,0.271c0.314,1.687,0.544,3.376,0.724,5.069c0.047,0.448,0.091,0.895,0.129,1.342
    c0.146,1.766,0.249,3.53,0.25,5.291c0,0.032,0.004,0.064,0.004,0.096c0,4.251-0.421,8.479-1.244,12.619
    c-0.974,4.902-2.544,9.671-4.623,14.229c-0.848,1.86-1.754,3.698-2.778,5.479c-5.033,8.728-7.691,18.676-7.691,28.752
    c0,9.737,2.475,19.584,7.697,28.632c5.856,10.149,8.65,21.261,8.65,32.203c0,4.113-0.394,8.201-1.163,12.212
    c0.011-0.008,0.024-0.02,0.036-0.027c1.389-1.197,2.837-2.312,4.313-3.382C33.33,140.325,33.652,140.104,33.973,139.881z" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>


<div class="clipped2 clipped"></div>
```

wrong:

[image]

right:

[image]

i have tried on image and not div. but nothing changed.
i have tried with viewbox but this will not work.
i have tried also clip-mask but the result is not so good and sharp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your clip-path coordinates are created in a custom coordinate system, instead of `clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox"` you should use [clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/clipPathUnits)

> This value indicates that all coordinates inside the 
> element refer to the user coordinate system as defined when the
> clipping path was created.

[image]

```css
.clipped{
    width:400px;
  height:400px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
}

.clipped2 {
  clip-path: url(#clip-shape2);
  background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/300/450);
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="0" height="0"  style="border:1px solid red" >
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip-shape2" clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse" >
<path transform="translate(2.2, 13) scale(2.5)" fill="none" stroke="black" d="M33.973,139.881c1.409-0.981,2.847-1.913,4.322-2.773c0.104-0.063,0.199-0.136,0.306-0.195
    c0.043-0.029,0.089-0.047,0.134-0.072c0.84-0.482,1.7-0.928,2.56-1.369c0.444-0.229,0.88-0.478,1.325-0.692
    c0.469-0.229,0.949-0.428,1.423-0.64c8.617-3.954,17.746-5.886,26.769-5.886c0.004,0,0.034,0,0.052,0
    c8.008-0.008,15.911-1.718,23.202-4.936c0.664-0.299,1.334-0.578,1.988-0.901c0.181-0.086,0.355-0.188,0.533-0.276
    c0.982-0.495,1.964-1.008,2.932-1.567c0.066-0.037,0.132-0.081,0.201-0.121c1.039-0.604,2.057-1.235,3.045-1.893
    c0.178-0.118,0.348-0.25,0.522-0.371c0.856-0.584,1.694-1.183,2.511-1.805c0.312-0.239,0.614-0.495,0.923-0.741
    c0.651-0.523,1.301-1.045,1.927-1.592c0.442-0.392,0.874-0.802,1.312-1.206c0.459-0.43,0.925-0.851,1.37-1.294
    c0.577-0.574,1.135-1.178,1.691-1.78c0.274-0.3,0.562-0.589,0.828-0.891c0.729-0.824,1.432-1.679,2.113-2.552
    c0.081-0.101,0.17-0.201,0.249-0.305c1.57-2.027,3.021-4.184,4.343-6.471c0.009-0.017,0.027-0.028,0.039-0.046
    c5.006-8.726,7.659-18.645,7.659-28.707c-0.006-9.732-2.477-19.584-7.698-28.623c-0.642-1.113-1.318-2.194-2.022-3.249
    c-0.028-0.042-0.054-0.086-0.079-0.128c-0.622-0.923-1.276-1.812-1.943-2.688c-0.128-0.168-0.24-0.343-0.372-0.508
    c-0.462-0.594-0.947-1.154-1.433-1.727c-2.533-3.001-5.356-5.742-8.446-8.168c-0.209-0.164-0.405-0.338-0.615-0.496
    c-0.59-0.447-1.199-0.865-1.804-1.293c-0.434-0.302-0.855-0.617-1.292-0.908c-0.42-0.274-0.852-0.528-1.275-0.795
    c-0.661-0.411-1.312-0.826-1.985-1.209c-0.229-0.132-0.467-0.249-0.703-0.379c-0.887-0.486-1.775-0.966-2.684-1.404
    c-0.037-0.02-0.074-0.034-0.115-0.052c-6.634-3.189-13.832-5.089-21.182-5.573c-1.235-0.078-2.478-0.124-3.731-0.124
    c-1.812,0-3.598-0.101-5.373-0.246c-0.33-0.027-0.661-0.067-0.991-0.102c-1.575-0.154-3.131-0.364-4.672-0.631
    c-0.207-0.036-0.414-0.069-0.622-0.105c-3.71-0.679-7.309-1.669-10.77-2.952c-0.01-0.004-0.019-0.007-0.026-0.013
    c-1.71-0.633-3.38-1.341-5.017-2.111c-0.134-0.064-0.271-0.125-0.406-0.189c-3.249-1.559-6.343-3.377-9.263-5.436
    c-0.38-0.27-0.753-0.546-1.128-0.822c-1.087-0.804-2.148-1.639-3.183-2.508c-0.243-0.205-0.508-0.382-0.751-0.592
    c0.018,0.091,0.021,0.181,0.039,0.271c0.314,1.687,0.544,3.376,0.724,5.069c0.047,0.448,0.091,0.895,0.129,1.342
    c0.146,1.766,0.249,3.53,0.25,5.291c0,0.032,0.004,0.064,0.004,0.096c0,4.251-0.421,8.479-1.244,12.619
    c-0.974,4.902-2.544,9.671-4.623,14.229c-0.848,1.86-1.754,3.698-2.778,5.479c-5.033,8.728-7.691,18.676-7.691,28.752
    c0,9.737,2.475,19.584,7.697,28.632c5.856,10.149,8.65,21.261,8.65,32.203c0,4.113-0.394,8.201-1.163,12.212
    c0.011-0.008,0.024-0.02,0.036-0.027c1.389-1.197,2.837-2.312,4.313-3.382C33.33,140.325,33.652,140.104,33.973,139.881z" />
    </clipPath>
    </defs>

</svg>

<div class="clipped2 clipped"></div>
```

### UPDATE

***Explanation of the need to apply the transformation:

`transform="translate(2.2, 13) scale(2.5)"`***

If the dimensions of the SVG shape are larger than the physical size of the SVG canvas defined by `viewBox`, then those parts of the shape that are larger will be clipped.
*Therefore, in your example, either the top of the clipPath or the bottom is cut off depending on the positioning.*

Goal: Find out the physical dimensions of the `clipPath` SVG and set the viewBox options to match those dimensions.
To determine the physical dimensions (as it was drawn in the editor), the JS `getBBox()` method is used:

```js
console.log(path.getBBox())
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  style="border:1px solid red" >
 <defs>
<path id="path"  fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" d="M33.973,139.881c1.409-0.981,2.847-1.913,4.322-2.773c0.104-0.063,0.199-0.136,0.306-0.195
    c0.043-0.029,0.089-0.047,0.134-0.072c0.84-0.482,1.7-0.928,2.56-1.369c0.444-0.229,0.88-0.478,1.325-0.692
    c0.469-0.229,0.949-0.428,1.423-0.64c8.617-3.954,17.746-5.886,26.769-5.886c0.004,0,0.034,0,0.052,0
    c8.008-0.008,15.911-1.718,23.202-4.936c0.664-0.299,1.334-0.578,1.988-0.901c0.181-0.086,0.355-0.188,0.533-0.276
    c0.982-0.495,1.964-1.008,2.932-1.567c0.066-0.037,0.132-0.081,0.201-0.121c1.039-0.604,2.057-1.235,3.045-1.893
    c0.178-0.118,0.348-0.25,0.522-0.371c0.856-0.584,1.694-1.183,2.511-1.805c0.312-0.239,0.614-0.495,0.923-0.741
    c0.651-0.523,1.301-1.045,1.927-1.592c0.442-0.392,0.874-0.802,1.312-1.206c0.459-0.43,0.925-0.851,1.37-1.294
    c0.577-0.574,1.135-1.178,1.691-1.78c0.274-0.3,0.562-0.589,0.828-0.891c0.729-0.824,1.432-1.679,2.113-2.552
    c0.081-0.101,0.17-0.201,0.249-0.305c1.57-2.027,3.021-4.184,4.343-6.471c0.009-0.017,0.027-0.028,0.039-0.046
    c5.006-8.726,7.659-18.645,7.659-28.707c-0.006-9.732-2.477-19.584-7.698-28.623c-0.642-1.113-1.318-2.194-2.022-3.249
    c-0.028-0.042-0.054-0.086-0.079-0.128c-0.622-0.923-1.276-1.812-1.943-2.688c-0.128-0.168-0.24-0.343-0.372-0.508
    c-0.462-0.594-0.947-1.154-1.433-1.727c-2.533-3.001-5.356-5.742-8.446-8.168c-0.209-0.164-0.405-0.338-0.615-0.496
    c-0.59-0.447-1.199-0.865-1.804-1.293c-0.434-0.302-0.855-0.617-1.292-0.908c-0.42-0.274-0.852-0.528-1.275-0.795
    c-0.661-0.411-1.312-0.826-1.985-1.209c-0.229-0.132-0.467-0.249-0.703-0.379c-0.887-0.486-1.775-0.966-2.684-1.404
    c-0.037-0.02-0.074-0.034-0.115-0.052c-6.634-3.189-13.832-5.089-21.182-5.573c-1.235-0.078-2.478-0.124-3.731-0.124
    c-1.812,0-3.598-0.101-5.373-0.246c-0.33-0.027-0.661-0.067-0.991-0.102c-1.575-0.154-3.131-0.364-4.672-0.631
    c-0.207-0.036-0.414-0.069-0.622-0.105c-3.71-0.679-7.309-1.669-10.77-2.952c-0.01-0.004-0.019-0.007-0.026-0.013
    c-1.71-0.633-3.38-1.341-5.017-2.111c-0.134-0.064-0.271-0.125-0.406-0.189c-3.249-1.559-6.343-3.377-9.263-5.436
    c-0.38-0.27-0.753-0.546-1.128-0.822c-1.087-0.804-2.148-1.639-3.183-2.508c-0.243-0.205-0.508-0.382-0.751-0.592
    c0.018,0.091,0.021,0.181,0.039,0.271c0.314,1.687,0.544,3.376,0.724,5.069c0.047,0.448,0.091,0.895,0.129,1.342
    c0.146,1.766,0.249,3.53,0.25,5.291c0,0.032,0.004,0.064,0.004,0.096c0,4.251-0.421,8.479-1.244,12.619
    c-0.974,4.902-2.544,9.671-4.623,14.229c-0.848,1.86-1.754,3.698-2.778,5.479c-5.033,8.728-7.691,18.676-7.691,28.752
    c0,9.737,2.475,19.584,7.697,28.632c5.856,10.149,8.65,21.261,8.65,32.203c0,4.113-0.394,8.201-1.163,12.212
    c0.011-0.008,0.024-0.02,0.036-0.027c1.389-1.197,2.837-2.312,4.313-3.382C33.33,140.325,33.652,140.104,33.973,139.881z" /> 
    
</defs> 
  <use xlink:href="#path" />
</svg>
```

The red border shows the borders of the SVG canvas, since the SVG header does not specify dimensions, the default size of the canvas will be `150x300 px`
Physical dimensions of the svg shape:

```
"x": 13.480993270874023,
  "y": -2.2320175170898438,
  "width": 114.77100372314453,
  "height": 146.19500732421875
```

Therefore, we set the value of the parameters: `viewBox="13.4 -2.2 114.7 146.2" and width="114.7" height="146.2"`
**In this case, the SVG shape will be completely inside the SVG canvas  and no part of it will be cut off**

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="114.7" height="146.2" viewBox="13.4 -2.2 114.7 146.2"  style="border:1px solid red" >
 <defs>
<path id="path"  fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" d="M33.973,139.881c1.409-0.981,2.847-1.913,4.322-2.773c0.104-0.063,0.199-0.136,0.306-0.195
    c0.043-0.029,0.089-0.047,0.134-0.072c0.84-0.482,1.7-0.928,2.56-1.369c0.444-0.229,0.88-0.478,1.325-0.692
    c0.469-0.229,0.949-0.428,1.423-0.64c8.617-3.954,17.746-5.886,26.769-5.886c0.004,0,0.034,0,0.052,0
    c8.008-0.008,15.911-1.718,23.202-4.936c0.664-0.299,1.334-0.578,1.988-0.901c0.181-0.086,0.355-0.188,0.533-0.276
    c0.982-0.495,1.964-1.008,2.932-1.567c0.066-0.037,0.132-0.081,0.201-0.121c1.039-0.604,2.057-1.235,3.045-1.893
    c0.178-0.118,0.348-0.25,0.522-0.371c0.856-0.584,1.694-1.183,2.511-1.805c0.312-0.239,0.614-0.495,0.923-0.741
    c0.651-0.523,1.301-1.045,1.927-1.592c0.442-0.392,0.874-0.802,1.312-1.206c0.459-0.43,0.925-0.851,1.37-1.294
    c0.577-0.574,1.135-1.178,1.691-1.78c0.274-0.3,0.562-0.589,0.828-0.891c0.729-0.824,1.432-1.679,2.113-2.552
    c0.081-0.101,0.17-0.201,0.249-0.305c1.57-2.027,3.021-4.184,4.343-6.471c0.009-0.017,0.027-0.028,0.039-0.046
    c5.006-8.726,7.659-18.645,7.659-28.707c-0.006-9.732-2.477-19.584-7.698-28.623c-0.642-1.113-1.318-2.194-2.022-3.249
    c-0.028-0.042-0.054-0.086-0.079-0.128c-0.622-0.923-1.276-1.812-1.943-2.688c-0.128-0.168-0.24-0.343-0.372-0.508
    c-0.462-0.594-0.947-1.154-1.433-1.727c-2.533-3.001-5.356-5.742-8.446-8.168c-0.209-0.164-0.405-0.338-0.615-0.496
    c-0.59-0.447-1.199-0.865-1.804-1.293c-0.434-0.302-0.855-0.617-1.292-0.908c-0.42-0.274-0.852-0.528-1.275-0.795
    c-0.661-0.411-1.312-0.826-1.985-1.209c-0.229-0.132-0.467-0.249-0.703-0.379c-0.887-0.486-1.775-0.966-2.684-1.404
    c-0.037-0.02-0.074-0.034-0.115-0.052c-6.634-3.189-13.832-5.089-21.182-5.573c-1.235-0.078-2.478-0.124-3.731-0.124
    c-1.812,0-3.598-0.101-5.373-0.246c-0.33-0.027-0.661-0.067-0.991-0.102c-1.575-0.154-3.131-0.364-4.672-0.631
    c-0.207-0.036-0.414-0.069-0.622-0.105c-3.71-0.679-7.309-1.669-10.77-2.952c-0.01-0.004-0.019-0.007-0.026-0.013
    c-1.71-0.633-3.38-1.341-5.017-2.111c-0.134-0.064-0.271-0.125-0.406-0.189c-3.249-1.559-6.343-3.377-9.263-5.436
    c-0.38-0.27-0.753-0.546-1.128-0.822c-1.087-0.804-2.148-1.639-3.183-2.508c-0.243-0.205-0.508-0.382-0.751-0.592
    c0.018,0.091,0.021,0.181,0.039,0.271c0.314,1.687,0.544,3.376,0.724,5.069c0.047,0.448,0.091,0.895,0.129,1.342
    c0.146,1.766,0.249,3.53,0.25,5.291c0,0.032,0.004,0.064,0.004,0.096c0,4.251-0.421,8.479-1.244,12.619
    c-0.974,4.902-2.544,9.671-4.623,14.229c-0.848,1.86-1.754,3.698-2.778,5.479c-5.033,8.728-7.691,18.676-7.691,28.752
    c0,9.737,2.475,19.584,7.697,28.632c5.856,10.149,8.65,21.261,8.65,32.203c0,4.113-0.394,8.201-1.163,12.212
    c0.011-0.008,0.024-0.02,0.036-0.027c1.389-1.197,2.837-2.312,4.313-3.382C33.33,140.325,33.652,140.104,33.973,139.881z" /> 
    
</defs> 
  <use xlink:href="#path" />
</svg>
```

To increase the size of `clipPath` increase the width and height of the custom viewport

```
width="114.7" x 2.5 =~ 286.7 
height="146.2" x 2.5 =~ 365,5
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="286.7" height="365,5" viewBox="13.4 -2.2 114.7 146.2"  style="border:1px solid red" >
 <defs>
<path id="path"  fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" d="M33.973,139.881c1.409-0.981,2.847-1.913,4.322-2.773c0.104-0.063,0.199-0.136,0.306-0.195
    c0.043-0.029,0.089-0.047,0.134-0.072c0.84-0.482,1.7-0.928,2.56-1.369c0.444-0.229,0.88-0.478,1.325-0.692
    c0.469-0.229,0.949-0.428,1.423-0.64c8.617-3.954,17.746-5.886,26.769-5.886c0.004,0,0.034,0,0.052,0
    c8.008-0.008,15.911-1.718,23.202-4.936c0.664-0.299,1.334-0.578,1.988-0.901c0.181-0.086,0.355-0.188,0.533-0.276
    c0.982-0.495,1.964-1.008,2.932-1.567c0.066-0.037,0.132-0.081,0.201-0.121c1.039-0.604,2.057-1.235,3.045-1.893
    c0.178-0.118,0.348-0.25,0.522-0.371c0.856-0.584,1.694-1.183,2.511-1.805c0.312-0.239,0.614-0.495,0.923-0.741
    c0.651-0.523,1.301-1.045,1.927-1.592c0.442-0.392,0.874-0.802,1.312-1.206c0.459-0.43,0.925-0.851,1.37-1.294
    c0.577-0.574,1.135-1.178,1.691-1.78c0.274-0.3,0.562-0.589,0.828-0.891c0.729-0.824,1.432-1.679,2.113-2.552
    c0.081-0.101,0.17-0.201,0.249-0.305c1.57-2.027,3.021-4.184,4.343-6.471c0.009-0.017,0.027-0.028,0.039-0.046
    c5.006-8.726,7.659-18.645,7.659-28.707c-0.006-9.732-2.477-19.584-7.698-28.623c-0.642-1.113-1.318-2.194-2.022-3.249
    c-0.028-0.042-0.054-0.086-0.079-0.128c-0.622-0.923-1.276-1.812-1.943-2.688c-0.128-0.168-0.24-0.343-0.372-0.508
    c-0.462-0.594-0.947-1.154-1.433-1.727c-2.533-3.001-5.356-5.742-8.446-8.168c-0.209-0.164-0.405-0.338-0.615-0.496
    c-0.59-0.447-1.199-0.865-1.804-1.293c-0.434-0.302-0.855-0.617-1.292-0.908c-0.42-0.274-0.852-0.528-1.275-0.795
    c-0.661-0.411-1.312-0.826-1.985-1.209c-0.229-0.132-0.467-0.249-0.703-0.379c-0.887-0.486-1.775-0.966-2.684-1.404
    c-0.037-0.02-0.074-0.034-0.115-0.052c-6.634-3.189-13.832-5.089-21.182-5.573c-1.235-0.078-2.478-0.124-3.731-0.124
    c-1.812,0-3.598-0.101-5.373-0.246c-0.33-0.027-0.661-0.067-0.991-0.102c-1.575-0.154-3.131-0.364-4.672-0.631
    c-0.207-0.036-0.414-0.069-0.622-0.105c-3.71-0.679-7.309-1.669-10.77-2.952c-0.01-0.004-0.019-0.007-0.026-0.013
    c-1.71-0.633-3.38-1.341-5.017-2.111c-0.134-0.064-0.271-0.125-0.406-0.189c-3.249-1.559-6.343-3.377-9.263-5.436
    c-0.38-0.27-0.753-0.546-1.128-0.822c-1.087-0.804-2.148-1.639-3.183-2.508c-0.243-0.205-0.508-0.382-0.751-0.592
    c0.018,0.091,0.021,0.181,0.039,0.271c0.314,1.687,0.544,3.376,0.724,5.069c0.047,0.448,0.091,0.895,0.129,1.342
    c0.146,1.766,0.249,3.53,0.25,5.291c0,0.032,0.004,0.064,0.004,0.096c0,4.251-0.421,8.479-1.244,12.619
    c-0.974,4.902-2.544,9.671-4.623,14.229c-0.848,1.86-1.754,3.698-2.778,5.479c-5.033,8.728-7.691,18.676-7.691,28.752
    c0,9.737,2.475,19.584,7.697,28.632c5.856,10.149,8.65,21.261,8.65,32.203c0,4.113-0.394,8.201-1.163,12.212
    c0.011-0.008,0.024-0.02,0.036-0.027c1.389-1.197,2.837-2.312,4.313-3.382C33.33,140.325,33.652,140.104,33.973,139.881z" /> 
    
</defs> 
  <use xlink:href="#path" />
</svg>
```

To avoid empty fields in your example, we set more precise values for the width and height of the parent container `.clipped`: instead of `400px`

```
.clipped{
  width:286.7px;
  height:365.5px;
```

```css
.clipped{
    width:286.7px;
  height:365.5px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
 
}

.clipped2 {
  clip-path: url(#clip-shape2);
  background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/300/450);
  
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="0" height="0" >
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip-shape2" clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse" >
<path transform="translate(2.2, 13) scale(2)" fill="none" stroke="black" d="M33.973,139.881c1.409-0.981,2.847-1.913,4.322-2.773c0.104-0.063,0.199-0.136,0.306-0.195
    c0.043-0.029,0.089-0.047,0.134-0.072c0.84-0.482,1.7-0.928,2.56-1.369c0.444-0.229,0.88-0.478,1.325-0.692
    c0.469-0.229,0.949-0.428,1.423-0.64c8.617-3.954,17.746-5.886,26.769-5.886c0.004,0,0.034,0,0.052,0
    c8.008-0.008,15.911-1.718,23.202-4.936c0.664-0.299,1.334-0.578,1.988-0.901c0.181-0.086,0.355-0.188,0.533-0.276
    c0.982-0.495,1.964-1.008,2.932-1.567c0.066-0.037,0.132-0.081,0.201-0.121c1.039-0.604,2.057-1.235,3.045-1.893
    c0.178-0.118,0.348-0.25,0.522-0.371c0.856-0.584,1.694-1.183,2.511-1.805c0.312-0.239,0.614-0.495,0.923-0.741
    c0.651-0.523,1.301-1.045,1.927-1.592c0.442-0.392,0.874-0.802,1.312-1.206c0.459-0.43,0.925-0.851,1.37-1.294
    c0.577-0.574,1.135-1.178,1.691-1.78c0.274-0.3,0.562-0.589,0.828-0.891c0.729-0.824,1.432-1.679,2.113-2.552
    c0.081-0.101,0.17-0.201,0.249-0.305c1.57-2.027,3.021-4.184,4.343-6.471c0.009-0.017,0.027-0.028,0.039-0.046
    c5.006-8.726,7.659-18.645,7.659-28.707c-0.006-9.732-2.477-19.584-7.698-28.623c-0.642-1.113-1.318-2.194-2.022-3.249
    c-0.028-0.042-0.054-0.086-0.079-0.128c-0.622-0.923-1.276-1.812-1.943-2.688c-0.128-0.168-0.24-0.343-0.372-0.508
    c-0.462-0.594-0.947-1.154-1.433-1.727c-2.533-3.001-5.356-5.742-8.446-8.168c-0.209-0.164-0.405-0.338-0.615-0.496
    c-0.59-0.447-1.199-0.865-1.804-1.293c-0.434-0.302-0.855-0.617-1.292-0.908c-0.42-0.274-0.852-0.528-1.275-0.795
    c-0.661-0.411-1.312-0.826-1.985-1.209c-0.229-0.132-0.467-0.249-0.703-0.379c-0.887-0.486-1.775-0.966-2.684-1.404
    c-0.037-0.02-0.074-0.034-0.115-0.052c-6.634-3.189-13.832-5.089-21.182-5.573c-1.235-0.078-2.478-0.124-3.731-0.124
    c-1.812,0-3.598-0.101-5.373-0.246c-0.33-0.027-0.661-0.067-0.991-0.102c-1.575-0.154-3.131-0.364-4.672-0.631
    c-0.207-0.036-0.414-0.069-0.622-0.105c-3.71-0.679-7.309-1.669-10.77-2.952c-0.01-0.004-0.019-0.007-0.026-0.013
    c-1.71-0.633-3.38-1.341-5.017-2.111c-0.134-0.064-0.271-0.125-0.406-0.189c-3.249-1.559-6.343-3.377-9.263-5.436
    c-0.38-0.27-0.753-0.546-1.128-0.822c-1.087-0.804-2.148-1.639-3.183-2.508c-0.243-0.205-0.508-0.382-0.751-0.592
    c0.018,0.091,0.021,0.181,0.039,0.271c0.314,1.687,0.544,3.376,0.724,5.069c0.047,0.448,0.091,0.895,0.129,1.342
    c0.146,1.766,0.249,3.53,0.25,5.291c0,0.032,0.004,0.064,0.004,0.096c0,4.251-0.421,8.479-1.244,12.619
    c-0.974,4.902-2.544,9.671-4.623,14.229c-0.848,1.86-1.754,3.698-2.778,5.479c-5.033,8.728-7.691,18.676-7.691,28.752
    c0,9.737,2.475,19.584,7.697,28.632c5.856,10.149,8.65,21.261,8.65,32.203c0,4.113-0.394,8.201-1.163,12.212
    c0.011-0.008,0.024-0.02,0.036-0.027c1.389-1.197,2.837-2.312,4.313-3.382C33.33,140.325,33.652,140.104,33.973,139.881z" />
    </clipPath>
    </defs>

</svg> 
<div class="clipped2 clipped"></div>
```

Comment: thank you! also for the examples and explanation!

Comment: @Donja   I can offer you an additional answer where I will share my knowledge of how to simply and universally create a path so that there are no problems with clipPath image cropping. Do you need such an additional answer?